# Why is python writing ` instead of @

Tags: python, pyautogui

So I'm trying to write a spam bot to annoy my friends in discord (I know I'm evil)
Here's the code

```
import time
import pyautogui
time.sleep(10)
victim = "Saka"
f = open("spamtext", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
    pyautogui.typewrite("@" + victim)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(1)
```

The problem is, instead of typing "@Saka", it types "`Saka".
I've tried `pyautogui.keyUp('shift')`, but it still doesn't work,any ideas?
(Also this is my first time asking a question here, so sorry if I didn't provide enough info)

Comment: I fixed the tags for your question. Tags should not be used to indicate why you are writing the code; they should be used to indicate what you are using and need help with.

Comment: it works for me properly, with `@` - windows 10 - python 3

Comment: please check your keyboard layout / set it `English` then run your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol! This is a funny post. Cheers to the prank.

With pyautogui, it literally presses the keyboard. Imagine a human robot doing it really fast. So you need to pass the exact keys you press in your keyboard to output the "@"

In order to do this, the función hotkey is available.

To make pressing hotkeys or keyboard shortcuts convenient, the hotkey() can be passed several key strings which will be pressed down in order, and then released in reverse order.

In my keyboard, I can output an @symbol with shift + 2 which I think it would be something like:

pyautogui.hotkey('shift', '2')

Comment: I mapped it to my keyboard, but still doesn't work :(, Thankyou for all the info tho, I'm new to python so it really helped me!

Comment: You are welcome, maybe your keyboard language is causing the problem. Try changing it to standard ENG US to use shift + 2. If you find it helpful, don´t forget to upvote hehe

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is about your keyboard layout,
So you can print at sign in ASCII, and be sure it works everywhere

```
import time
import pyautogui
time.sleep(10)
victim = "Saka"
at_sign = chr(64) # 64 is at-sign ascii character: @
f = open("spamtext", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(at_sign + victim)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: still out puts `Saka :( Maybe its for the better this won't work XD. Thanks for helping tho!

Comment: how you type `@` in your computer? I mean the key combinations?  shift + 2 or what?

Comment: I use a Japanese keyboard, so it has it's own key for @ that doesn't require you to press down shift. It's the key next to" P"

Comment: What is your OS? windows/mac/linux

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone for your help! The thing was that Japanese keyboard doesn't work well with pyautogui because it has 2 modes, English and Japanese, which it keeps switching between. All I had to do was download US keyboard and now I think my friends hate me...

Thanks to Martin Castellon for the help!